# Unable to use the values of child nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to transform the XML and use the value of child node in a new node. I tried, but was unable fetch the value of child node.

This is the XML that I want to transform

```
<InvoiceDocument>
    <Invoice>
        <a>120</a>
        <Products>
            <Product>
                <b>11</b>  <!-- Modified by edit -->
            </Product>
            <Product>
                <c>12</c>
            </Product>
        </Products>
    </Invoice>
</InvoiceDocument>
```

This is the required output

```
 <InvoiceDocument>
    <d>120</a>
    <e>11<b>
    <f>12</c>
  </InvoiceDocument>
```

This is the code that i tried using to fetch the value of the child node and use it in another node

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="InvoiceDocument">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Invoice"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Product"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Invoice">
  <d><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(a/text()[1])"/></d>
  </xsl:template>


   <xsl:template match="Product">
  <e><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(b/text()[1])"/></e>
  <f><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(c/text()[1])"/></f>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried the above code, but was unable to use the value of the child node.

Answer (score 0):

Change your XSLT stylesheet to the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />               <!-- Removes empty lines -->

  <xsl:template match="InvoiceDocument">         <!-- Creates the InvoiceDocument element in the output -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <d><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Invoice/a[1])"/></d>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />                <!-- Ignore un-matched text() nodes -->

  <xsl:template match="Product/b[1]">            <!-- Creates the <e> element from the first <b> element in Products -->
    <e><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></e>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Product/c[1]">            <!-- Creates the <f> element from the first <c> element in Products -->
    <f><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></f>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<InvoiceDocument>
    <d>120</d>
    <e>11</e>
    <f>12</f>
</InvoiceDocument>
```

Comment: Can i use the Product node directly under Invoice Document

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I updated my answer with a slightly changed approach.

Comment: Can i match all the elements inside the Product node at once rather than matching them one by one

Comment: Yes. You can do this with `<xsl:template match="Product/*">...`. This matches all children of all `<Product>` elements in one template. But then you have to differentiate for the output of `<e>` and `<f>` elements.